# Transmission delay of multi-lane vs single-lane Ethenet

Tags: ethernet, fiber

Suppose there are two devices that can transmit with same throughput (e.g., 10Gb/s).
Suppose that one device is connected via single-lane cable while the other with multi-lanes (e.g., 8 lanes).
Will the transmission delay be affected by the number of lanes?

Comment: Both will transmit 10 Gbps. That means that the hosts sending the data will put the data on the wire at the same rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the lanes are in parallel, the transmission delay is the same regardless of the number of lanes.

Comment: Thanks :)
Follow question: in multi-lane ethernet, are the lanes are synchronisys? i.e., if the symbol of byte 1 of a packet is sent in lane 1, the symbol of byte 2 of a packet is sent in lane 2, then symbol of byte 1 will be received before byte 2?

Comment: You should ask a separate question about that.

Comment: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70671/implementation-of-multi-lane-ethernet Done :)